# How to do set post permalinks using 6 digit random unique function?

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, permalinks, wpdb

I need the following: e.g.

**www.e.g.com/**`hello-world`

to

**www.e.g.com/**`9xY52a`

of course function check `9xY52a` inside the databese posts.

Comment: Please check [Random permalink key in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762070/random-permalink-key-in-wordpress#11762698) ... Hope this can help you

Comment: @Anish ty, but this code get "Cannot redeclare wp_unique_post_slug()" error message.

Comment: Having random 6 digit random unique code on your permalink feels like a cool idea but your site will not have a good index on Google .

One of the major on-page SEO factors is having your user friendly keyword in your post URL (permalink).

Comment: @OnurBoz There is a [Filter on wp_unique_post_slug()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3790) you can get logic from above link and replace slug using WordPress's [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)